# Advanced search in ADO. Net Windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

I have the below ADO.Net code written in c# to get the detail of the student from the student table when the user puts either the roll number or the student name. The problem is that, it was all fine when the search was being performed using only one column but I want to use either condition on columns. Does anybody have any idea if this thing is possible in the below code.The below code is throwing me an error saying:

> incorrect syntax near OR.

```
comm = new SqlCommand("select * from student_detail where (roll_no = '%" + txtRollNumber.Text + "%') OR (s_name = '"+ txtStudentName.Text +"')", conn);
```

Comment: What is either condition ?? also, try using stored procedure to do that.

Comment: I want to search using either of the two textboxes i.e. either by using s_name or by roll_no. Is it not possible in this command object to use both  columns

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work

Answer (score 0):

You have a % in your sql query which is a special wildcard character that is only use in LIKE clauses.

Try this:

```
comm = new SqlCommand("select * from student_detail 
                       where (roll_no = '" + txtRollNumber.Text + "') 
                       OR (s_name = '" + txtStudentName.Text + "')"
                       ,conn);
```

Comment: You had a % in your sql query which is a special wildcard character that is only use in LIKE clauses.

Comment: No. The thing which worked is by using roll_no = '" + txtRollNumber.Text + "' in place of roll_no = ' + txtRollNumber.Text + ". But how it worked is still out of the box because generally we put integer field inside " " and not inside ' " " '

Comment: what will be the code if i want to put the search result based on the value i am putting into textbox into datagrid??

Comment: That would be a totally different question and answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Just be aware, that you're not sanitising your inputs in your example. So, if someone puts a backtick in txtStudentName they can effectively run commands on your database. It's called SQL Injection.
I suggest you look into how you can use Parameterized Queries in ADO.NET (it's really very, very easy) - this will make your code (well actually your database) much safer.